# Make Swagger don't display model name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

Swager is used with ASP.NET Web API. Here is part of code which is used

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(ModelResult))]
[Route("GetModel")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetUser([FromUri]ModelType model)
```

For some strange reason in some APIs in Swagger this info is displayed in such way
[image: Swagger display]

Normally there is no `model.` displayed and Web API's auto-generated docs display it without `model.`. Is there any way to remove it?